# How long would it take an average person to climb an one-hundred and twenty billion feet tower?

Tags: science-based, megastructures

I saw a recap of a film called Fall released this year. It is about 2 girls stuck on the 4th highest structure(supposedly) in the USA. It got me to thinking about very tall things and climbing them. I also like the idea of something being tall enough to were it takes a while to hit the ground.

So i came up with a tower 120,000,000,000 tall to fall for almost 1 day/24 hours(not technically 24 hours but close enough), if the the climber is unfortunate to experience that. So how long would it take the average person to climb a tower that tall given there is a ladder. What about taking the stairs instead? What if there was no structures meant for it and you had to free climb?

You can handwave things like needing food/water, bathroom breaks, sleep, and the tower being far too massive to support its own weight by the fact I would plan this happening in a mostly lifelike simulation/VR program that has perceived time speed up but otherwise has no barring on this answer.

Comment: Do you realize that that distance is about 1/4 of the distance between Earth and the Sun?

Comment: It's unclear if you are asking us to query Google for your ("*How fast does a human climb stairs?*"), or if you are asking us to do the basic maths to convert that answer impossibly silly and unrealistic for you (perhaps 3500 years by stairs), or if you are asking something else.

Comment: Does the elevator work?

Comment: @SeanOConnor at these distances, you are going to spend waaay too long in an elevator too. Best case, you simply teleport to the top or the simulation starts there.

Comment: @vinzzz001 But the music might be nice.

Comment: Tape down the 'up' button and go AFK. Then complain about poor software design on social media.

Comment: The question is actually a good bit more interesting if you properly consider the physics. Climbing in space != climbing on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: HOw long did it take an Apollo capsule to fall from the  Moon to the Earth, adistance of about 1,189,633,000 feet?  About 3 days.  Why do you assume that the tower has to be 1,200,000,000 feet tall for the fall tolast one day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Stairway to Heaven (is anything but)**

A 120B ft tall tower is ~22.7M miles high. That's about 2/3 the Sun-Mercury distance. According to [this source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.1024.1309%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwixj42bl4D6AhUiSjABHVygCycQFnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2tvIBK7uYtxleOsFTKx80r), the average ascent speed on stairs is around 1.5 ft/s. That works out to around 80B seconds to ascend, or 2,536 years, climbing non-stop.

If you divide the climbing into 16 hour shifts, with 8 hours for sleep between shifts, the time to reach the summit increases to 3,400 years.

You'd go mad before reaching even a small fraction of the distance.

Comment: Haha, it needs to be only 120 million steps to be 'realistic'.

Comment: I can't make it for 25 minutes on the stair-climbing machine at the gym.

Comment: @JohnO I imagine that at first you might do 25 minutes climbing followed by a 2 hour break, but after a some years of training you would be able to climb a few hours at a time. And by year 1000 you would be fit enough to climb all day. (but at that point, do you still only ascend at the rate of the average human?)

Comment: This is incorrectly assuming that climbing is the same regardless of altitude.

Comment: @Fhnuzoag it's also *incorrectly* assuming  climbing is the same regardless of air pressure, centrifugal acceleration, etc. etc. I answered in the spirit of the question, a made-up VR world. Clearly the whole scenario defies reality so it's pointless overanalyzing everything.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.

**Actually this might be WAY easier than you think, if your tower is in the right place.**

This is because after a certain point (specifically, once you get beyond the altitude for geostationary orbit), the net force you feel will stop being down, but rather you would be flung *outwards* by the tower. (Assuming you are holding onto it!)

Let's assume the tower is on the equator. The total acceleration you feel will be approximately:

ω^2r - GM/r^2

where ω is your rate of angular rotation in radians per second and r is your distance from the center of the earth. If we simplify away the /r^2 part (gravitational attraction to the Earth is only 2% of normal at geostationary orbit), and solve the differential equation, we get:

r(t) = Aexp(ωt) + Bexp(-ωt)

Let's say we start stationary at 10m above geostationary orbit, then A=B=42164010/2

The second term disappears quickly, so solving and ignoring that term, we require around (8/ (2pi/(86400))) seconds to reach 120 billion feet.

That's about 1.3 days.

To actually reach geostationary orbit will take some time. You'll have to climb 35k km, though it'll get easier (due to centrifugal acceleration) as you go, so let's halve it as an approximation. Using the 1.5 ft/s number others used, that will take 7e7 seconds climbing nonstop. Or about 2.2 years.

So yes. **Even if you climb only 8 hours a day, you can reach 120 billion feet off the ground in under 7 years.**

Getting back down again will be problematic, though. You will be travelling away from the Earth a bit faster than 1% of the speed of light.

If your tower is on the (rotational) poles of the Earth, then you won't get this benefit. Still, gravity will get weaker and weaker as you go up, eventually becoming negligible. Your speed will be bounded only by how effectively you can propel yourself.

If you figure that out, the average labourer can put in about 75 watts of work. Working 8 hour days for a year at 100% efficiency will get you up to a speed of about 4km/s, which will get you there in 100 days. If you can't and so are limited to the speed of a human kick (about 100 km/h), it'll take about 42 years.

So it's doable.

Comment: “ You will be travelling away from the Earth a bit faster than 1% of the speed of light.” Yeah I think that might kill you

Comment: Well, it'll be the "accelerating at up to 20 Gs" that will kill you. That said, liquid breathing might let you survive that. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/491797/91939

Comment: (Alternatively you can just let go of the tower once enough velocity has been reached)

Answer (score 1):

## About 7 years because planets rotate

Geostationary orbit s at 35,786 km (22,236 miles). If your ladder is on the equator, your climber will gradually experience less and less resistance to climb as you approach this altitude.

When the climber is at this altitude, they are now in orbit and will experience a sort of weightlessness, as they continue to "climb" they will actually start to feel like they are going down instead of up and even being pushed into or away from the ladder (depending on orientation). The ladder now is more a sling than a slide and will launch the climber off the tip of the end of the ladder (provided you assume the climber can hold on until then).

As far as how long it will take, at 1.5 ft/s for the first 35,786 km that's 2.5 years, and about the same for the second 35,786 km going "down", but still up, after a little over 5 years in, you can safely assume that your "climber" is now a slider and will be accelerating and will probably reach the end of your ladder by the end of the 6th year.

Answer (score 0):

Average speeds for climbing stairs are one thing, but how many people can maintain that all day? Are those really the numbers we should we be looking at?

As pointed out by others, this journey will last thousands of years. Let's ignore human lifespan for a second and just go with it. At first our average person climbing will not be able to climb stairs all day nonstop, but after 100 years of training we can assume they would be at the fitness level of [ultrarunners](https://www.redbull.com/ca-en/best-male-ultra-runners). So how quickly could some of the best ultrarunners do it?

Going with an achievement mentioned in the first runner from the list within the link above, Ryan Sandes [ran the Great Himalaya Trail in just over 25 days](https://www.salomon.com/en-ca/blog/ryan-sandes-1504-km-himalayan-adventure) (25 days 4 hours and 24 minutes). Through its ups and downs, the trail has a total elevation gain of [88,000 meters](http://www.philippegatta.fr/ght2.htm#:%7E:text=In%20addition%20to%20this%20impressive,is%20close%20to%2088%2C000%20meters.) (~289K feet). Assuming that it has just as much descent and some flat parts, let's say he spent one third of his time climbing, one third on flat trail, and one third on descending sections. Our new ascent speed for an ultra fit person whose body is trained for endurance climbing would be able to climb 289K feet in 8.4 days, or 34.4K feet per day.

This works out to 3,488,372 days, or 9,557 years.